# PHP magic __get not working for variable in abstract base class

Tags: php, abstract-class, magic-methods

In my project, I'm using class inheritance a lot.
Now I notice that my magic getter is not triggering when I want to access a variable in the base class.
Hence the following code:

```php
abstract class A
{
    protected $varA;

    final public function __get($var)
    {
        echo $var;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    protected $varB;
}

class C extends A
{
    public function test()
    {
        $test = new B();
        $test->varB; // Get output
        $test->varA; // No output
    }
}

$test = new C();
$test->test();
```

Comment: Works fine for me: http://3v4l.org/Je7dN

Comment: Strange, not working here on my local machine (even the derived code that I put online). Time for a PHP update (5.6.2 right now, maybe it does work in 5.6.4).

Comment: 3v4l has checked 5.6.2 version. Is this exactly code that you are running on your local machine?

Comment: sorry for my previous answer. Work for me too.
PHP 5.5.3-1ubuntu2.6 (cli) (built: Jul  7 2014 16:54:32)

Comment: No, it's not exact the same. It's derived but it should do the same. The original code is way too big. But my derivation was wrong, I've updated the code fragment now. Even 3v4l does not show output now...

Comment: you mistake, all work correct. From CHILD class protected var is NOT inaccessible. Child class see varA, but varA is null. http://3v4l.org/7gUPa

Comment: [delete] ... ah, got it :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now I see that you faced with php feature. Visibility of properties relies on classes but not on the objects.

> Objects of the same type will have access to each others private and
>   protected members even though they are not the same instances. This is
>   because the implementation specific details are already known when
>   inside those objects.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php#example-208

Comment: Ok... So it's a fault in the OO implementation of PHP... This mean I'll need to rethink the project design.

Comment: @Blaatpraat, you never can be sure (with php): is that feature or fault. % )

Comment: This is infact not what is going on. A protected variable is visible outside the object. it is simply not accessible. you will get a Fatal error is you try to access a protected variable. A private variable on the other hand is not visible outside the class and will return undefined. as stated in the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: @Pinoniq, what do you mean by 'visible' and 'not accessible'?

Comment: public and protected variables are visible outside the object but only public variables are accessible outside the object. protected variables are accessible inside the object (also objects extending it). The __get is called if a property is not visible.

Comment: @Pinoniq, could explain (using a code) protected variables visibility with no accessibility from outside of object.

Answer (score 0):

__get is only triggered if the property **does not exist**.

varA is a property of you object. The oly problem is that it is protected. thus not accessible from outside your class.

Comment: According to the PHP documentation: "__get() is utilized for reading data from inaccessible properties.". It is inaccessible from this scope...

Comment: @Blaatpraat who says `$varA` is unaccessible from C? It is `protected`, not `private`.

Comment: @Cthulhu: this answer was here before my code update. Next to that: it still should be inaccassible. I'm trying to access a variable outside the class instance. If it was private, nor B or C should be able to access it.

Comment: @Blaatpraat ok you are outside this instance, but inside another instance of derived class.

Comment: @Cthulhu: still another instance. Protected variables shouldn't be accessible from another instance, only inside the own class and extensions of it. Otherwise you could make it public.

Comment: They are not accessible, but they are visible. this is as stated in the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php Protected variables are visible outside the object, they are simply not accessible. Big difference. Because __GET actes on the 'not visible'

Answer (score 0):

From CHILD class protected var is available. Child class see varA, but varA is null

Answer (score 0):

$varA is a protected variable of Class A.

Class B & C are extensions of Class A.

So $varA exists in an instance of C or B, because protected variables are accessible and assignable in the children of the class they are defined in. That's what they're for.

Since $varA exists, the __get is not triggered.

I'm not sure what you would expect to be different?

Comment: $varA exists in both indeed. But in an instance of Class C I don't expect that I can see the protected variables of Class B...

Comment: Ah right, now I see what you mean. That's indeed a weird implementation choice for PHP.